# How to fix Typedef variable not identified error in C++ (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c++

I have a few alias type defined for existing data types in a header file. On using alias to define variables in my code (which includes said header file), alias does not get identified as type. Looking for recommendations to resolve this error. Language - C++, IDE - Visual Studio 2017

Definition in header file:

```
#ifndef HD_DEFINES_H_DEFINE      
#define HD_DEFINES_H_DEFINE      
#include <limits.h>      
#ifdef __cplusplus      
extern "C"       
{      
#endif      
typedef unsigned int HDuint;      
typedef unsigned char HDboolean;      
typedef unsigned long HDulong;      
typedef unsigned short HDushort;      
typedef int HDint;      
typedef float HDfloat;      
typedef double HDdouble;      
typedef long HDlong;      
typedef char HDchar;      
typedef unsigned int HDerror;      
typedef unsigned int HDenum;      
typedef const char *HDstring;      
typedef unsigned int HHD;      
typedef struct      
{      
    HDerror errorCode; /* The HD_ error code */      
    int internalErrorCode; /* The original internal device-generated error */      
    HHD hHD; /* The handle of the current device when the error occurred */      
} HDErrorInfo;
```

Usage in code:(Code is including the said header file)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sstream>

#include <HL/hl.h>
#include <HD/hd.h>
#include <HD/hdDefines.h>
#include <HDU/hduError.h>
#include <HDU/hduVector.h>
#include <HDU/hduMatrix.h>

struct DeviceData{
    HDboolean m_buttonState;       
    hduVector3Dd m_devicePosition; 
    HDErrorInfo m_error
};
```

Error Message:

```
<error-type> HDboolean
variable "HDboolean" is not a type name
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]. The error cannot be reproduced with the code given, and the mistake is likely in code you didn't show.

Comment: Your `typedef`s are fine.  I'm guessing that either 1) the code that uses the types is not `#include`'ing the header file that defines them, or 2) the header file has a faulty header guard that causes the definitions to be skipped. Hard to say for sure without a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for replying. edited code for more details.

Comment: It still compiles (once I strip out the `#include`s for files I don't have and comment out the declaration of `m_devicePosition` since I lack the definition of its type). Keep in mind that we need a *minimal* and *reproducible* example. **Reproducible:** copy the code to a file (or an online compiler) and compile it. Make sure the compile error occurs *with what you give us*. **Minimal:** get rid of lines not needed to reproduce, such as most of those `#include`s.

Answer (score 0):

Typedefs look perfectly fine, so, my best guess, they aren't really included because of some ifdef mess, things like accidentally copy & pasting that #ifndef HD_DEFINES_H_DEFINE from another file, so more than one header has this same define (will cause the second header to not get included) and stuff like that.

A way to check if your stuff really gets included is rather straight forward, just put some junk before the typedef in question. Something like this:

```
foo foo foo
typedef unsigned char HDboolean;
```

Then build the project again. If it doesn't fail, start looking at your ifdefs and whats wrong with them. Possibly consider using "#pragma once" if the compiler in question supports it.

Comment: In addition to the compiler supporting `#pragma once`, you should also make sure your build system doesn't break `#pragma once` with tricksy symlinks and poorly synchronized clocks.

Comment: Since the OP is using Visual Studio, use `#pragma message("Some message")` to determine if a file is being included.  That message inside the pragma will show up in the compiler output.  There is no need to put something in the code that makes the compile fail.

Comment: Have to admit, I've never experienced a broken #pragma once. As for checking it with pragma mesage, or simply putting junk there, does it really matter? I tend to just type some junk, while, of course, it can be checked with the message. Message can be more useful if you want to know your exact include order you end up with, but the very fact this order matters usually means you are doing something wrong already.

Comment: *simply putting junk there, does it really matter?* -- I just don't think it's wise to stop a compilation from happening unless it is the `#error` being invoked, or a `static_assert`.  Putting mistakes in code is hazardous.

Comment: _Putting mistakes in code is hazardous_ - fair enough